# Printing S3 hosted private PDF with HTML iFrame proxy and Javascript - blank page in webkit

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, amazon-s3

I'm working on an application where we are using [PDFJS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to render PDFs in-app. These PDFs are hosted at S3, which makes printing them tricky due to cross-origin issues.

We built a special view which serves as an iframe proxy, and is hosted on our server (to remove cross-origin). The iframe proxy in turn loads another iframe which has the actual S3 PDF content.

In FireFox, we can successfully print our proxy iframe by running:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('printIframe') 
iframe.focus()
iframe.contentWindow.print()
```

However, in Chrome and Safari, this method produces a blank page. Any ideas out there?

We've also tested `var pdfWindow = window.open( pdfUrl ); pdfWindow.print();` but this is equally unsuccessful.

edit for detail:

The iframe proxy code is pretty straightforward.

We're hosting `iframe_proxy.html?path-to-s3-file.pdf`, which populates the nested iFrame like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body,
    iframe {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-style: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" src="path-to-s3-file.pdf" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: I just checked the code, unfortunately it appears we abandoned the effort. No idea if things have changed from over 4 years ago, I guess the feature wasn't important enough for our customers to care. If you find any new information it'd be great to add here :-) Cheers